# Issues on updating a subscriber using InvokeUpdate AMPScript function)

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm able to create a subscriber to the list with the below code. But I'm not able to update a subscriber (with the InvokeUpdate function) if the email already exists?

```
SET @subscriber = CreateObject("Subscriber") 
SetObjectProperty(@subscriber,"EmailAddress",@var_emailaddress)
SetObjectProperty(@subscriber,"SubscriberKey",@var_emailaddress)

SET @attribute = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@attribute,"Name","FirstName")
SetObjectProperty(@attribute,"Value",@var_firstname)
AddObjectArrayItem(@subscriber, "Attributes", @attribute) 

SET @attribute = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@attribute,"Name","LastName")
SetObjectProperty(@attribute,"Value",@var_lastname)
AddObjectArrayItem(@subscriber, "Attributes", @attribute)

Set @options = CreateObject("UpdateOptions") 
Set @save = CreateObject("SaveOption") 
SetObjectProperty(@save,"SaveAction","UpdateAdd") 
SetObjectProperty(@save,"PropertyName","Attribute") 
AddObjectArrayItem(@options,"SaveOptions", @save)

SET @list = CreateObject("SubscriberList")
SetObjectProperty(@list, "Status", "Active")
SetObjectProperty(@list, "ID", "VALID EXISTING LIST ID")
AddObjectArrayItem(@subscriber, "Lists", @list)

SET @statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@subscriber, @statusMsg, @errorCode, @options)

IF @statusCode == "OK" THEN 
   Redirect('http:')
ELSEIF @statusCode != "OK" THEN
    SET @statusCode = InvokeCreate(@subscriber, @statusMsg, @errorCode, @options)
    IF @statusCode == "OK" THEN
       Redirect('http:')
    ELSE 
       Redirect('http:') 
    ENDIF
ELSE
   Redirect('http:')
ENDIF
```

This while code can update plus create the subscriber list.

Comment: Are you setting the SubscriberKey Attribute when updating?

Comment: not in the code but the subscriber key is being filled with email address in the exacttarget subscriber lists.

Comment: you should say that this code is updated with Alex Finger's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Cannot Create a List and Update a Subscriber in the same call. Can only add a Subscriber to a List that is already created.

Change List code to:

```
SET @list = CreateObject("SubscriberList")
SetObjectProperty(@list, "Status", "Active")
SetObjectProperty(@list, "ID", "VALID EXISTING LIST ID")
AddObjectArrayItem(@subscriber, "Lists", @list)
```

2) It would seem that creating a SubscriberList via the InvokeCreate function is not possible (or highly difficult). Please someone correct me if I am wrong. I only get Errors like:
**ListNotFound**  and
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

It sounds like you may not be able to create a SubscriberList on the fly. I would reach out to ExactTarget for additional support if this is a must.

Comment: I changed the list code .. nice.. as you said ...can't create and update at the same time ...if i use InvokeUpdate function i can only update and if i use InvokeCreate function then i can only create..now i have to think how to haev one code page and do both

Comment: WITH YOUR POINTERS I CAN BE ABLE TO FINISH THE TASK..THX

Answer (score 0):

Set the SubscriberKey with the email address in the AMPScript.

Comment: am not using any API or sth..It is just a form LandingPage with script..

Comment: Edited. Set the SubscriberKey in addition to the Email Address (with the Email Address)

Comment: I added and changed the function to InvokeUpdate... now can't create nor update..

Comment: Is this in an email or a landing page? Do you get an error?

Comment: Its a landing page form.I dont get an error..it just redirect me to else page

Comment: Please remove the line:
IF @statusCode == "OK" THEN Redirect('http:') ELSE Redirect('http:')

And add the line: v(@statusMsg)

Comment: Am trying now ...

Comment: when i only use invokecreate function and  tried to get all msg  and i get this : statusmsg is : The subscriber is already on the list  
errocode is : 12014  
option is : ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL.UpdateOptions  
status code is : Error

Comment: Right, that means the subscriber already exists in the All Subscribers master list. You need to use InvokeUpdate if that is the case.

Comment: WITH YOUR POINTERS I CAN BE ABLE TO FINISH THE TASK..THX